# How to execute shell commands in browser without activex

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner developer in front-end development and i want to run a bash command from browser. 
Actually i want to run an application where is in client machine from browser. I'm not looking for ActiveX or other things that are not supported by all browsers. Do i have to develop an browser extension? If it is, how can i do that? I need your help guys.

As an example, open -a ApplicationName (parameters)

Comment: I havent done that but this looks promising [shell.php](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/06/command-line-access-using-shell-php/)

Comment: Firsly, thank you for answering, however my problem is running an application in client's machine. Your example show how to run shell in server

Comment: This is a huge security risk, what if someone execute `rm -rf *` ? This [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211118/execute-a-shell-command-upon-a-click-event-in-a-web-page) can help you.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but i did it in windows os, when i execute an exe first time, it adds an custom protocol to regedit, whenever i redirect current page to protocolName:/// (parameters) from javascript , it run the application where in client with the given parameters.